# Citation completion in vim latex-suite on Windows 8.1 Update

Tags: bibliographies, vim, vim-latex

This is potentially a duplicate of this [tex.se question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52662/getting-cite-autocompletion-to-work-in-gvim-with-latex-suite-on-windows-7), but I tried all the advice with still no solution.

I am on 64-bit Windows 8.1 Update with gvim 7.4, Python 2.7.7 (Anaconda 2.0.1 32-bit), and pywin32-214. I think the pywin is a little dated, but works best with my [vim-R-plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2628) for use with [R](http://www.r-project.org/).

When I type `\cite{Fama}` and press <kbd>F9</kbd> I get a flash, and it looks like it goes from normal back to insert, but I get neither an error nor a lower half split with matched .bib file entries. But my `\ref{}` completion works great. I use the *latexmain file setup, but the problem (i.e., no citation completion) works whether I do this or some MWE.

I have the following in my _vimrc file.

```
set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*
let g:Tex_BIBINPUTS='C:/Users/richa_000/texmf/bibtex/bib/library.bib'
```

I also have GNUgrep in path and `:!grep -V` returns the following.

```
C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c (grep -V)
GNU grep 2.5.4

Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Hit any key to close this window...
```

I also have Python in path and `:python import sys; print(sys.version)` returns the version listed above.

I also [vim-pandoc](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc) and can get citation completion there with `<C-x> <C-o>`.

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I am now having the same problem. Damn windows 8.1...